# SQL queries in shapefiles using python/gdal return none result

Tags: python, gdal, sql, ogr, python-2.7

I want try use Python and GDAL to create some SQL queries in my shapefiles.
I try something and it looks good, but doesn't work. I get a `none` result.

Here is the code :

```
from osgeo import ogr
ogr_ds = ogr.Open('line.shp')
TEST=3
sql = "SELECT id FROM {} where id='{}'".format(ogr_ds,TEST)
layer = ogr_ds.ExecuteSQL(sql)
print layer
```

Comment: Does your SQL find something when you run it with ogrinfo?

Comment: no I need like this in editor with python but I sure to have value

Comment: I meant that do you know that the SQL part is OK? Test with `ogrinfo -sql "SELECT id FROM line where id=3" line.shp`. If you get "3" it is OK and the issue can only be in your Python code.

Comment: yes I get it I take correct result now how to do in python ?

Comment: I guess that you have only opened the GDAL datasource but not the layer and you should get first a layer to query with something like layer = dataSource.GetLayer(). Taken from an example https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#get-shapefile-feature-count.

Comment: It was not meant for copy-paste but to make you think. I do not use python myself, sorry.

Comment: from osgeo import ogr
import os

shapefile = "line.shp"
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dataSource = driver.Open(shapefile, 0)
layer1 = dataSource.GetLayer()
TEST=3

sql = "SELECT id FROM {} where id={}".format(shapefile,TEST)
print sql
layer = shapefile.ExecuteSQL(sql)
print layer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using the input layer in a wrong way; furthermore, also the `.format{}` operation doesn't seem correct.

You may try the following code:

```
from osgeo import ogr

filepath = 'C:/Users/path_to_the_shapefile/line.shp' # set the filepath
layer_name = filepath[:-4].split('/')[-1] # get the layer name
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName ("ESRI Shapefile")
ogr_ds = driver.Open(filepath)
TEST=3
sql = "SELECT id FROM %s WHERE id=%s" %(layer_name,TEST)
layer = ogr_ds.ExecuteSQL(sql)
print layer
```

I tested it with another shapefile (and a similar query) and it returns what expected:

```
print layer
<osgeo.ogr.Layer; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRLayerShadow *' at 0x18A4D8F0> >
```

**EDIT**

If you want to print the `id` value, you may add these lines:

```
feat = layer.GetNextFeature()
val = feat.GetField(0)
print val
```

but this will only returns **one** feature and not all the queried features (this kind of operation would be useful if you are only interested in knowing if a specific value for the `id` field is stored in the input layer). Furthermore, you will get an error if there isn't any `id` value equals to the `TEST` variable.

Comment: show me `driver` not define

Comment: @jessiejes Sorry, there was a missing line. I edited the answer.

Comment: now I take this `<osgeo.ogr.Layer; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRLayerShadow *' at 0x03166D88> >` but I need the id for example if  select id is 6 then I need to take only this value 6 in the print layer