# SQL query in Python console to sum column based on values of other two columns

Tags: pyqgis, sql, qgis-2, virtual-layer, summarizing

We have 100's of shapefiles for which we have to generate excel reports based on a few (combination of) parameters in the attribute table. I am using SQL query to achieve this and when I run the query in the "Create Virtual layer" process, it works fine and the output has been generated, which will be saved as an excel file. Instead of this process, I am trying to run this through the Python console. Though the code didn't show any error, the output is not being printed. Do I have to change the SQL query format in the code?

Image 1: For the shapefile ***final_bdry***, Total_Area has to be calculated based on two other columns - ***MS_Area, Ground_Con*** (similar to Pivot_Table in excel, the sum of a column based on a unique count of the other two columns). No issues with the query and I am getting the desired output in the virtual_layer.
[image].

Image 2: But, if I run the same query within the Python console, the result is `"None"`

[image]

*Ref:* Used this as ref [SQL queries in shapefiles using python/gdal return none result](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238334/sql-queries-in-shapefiles-using-python-gdal-return-none-result/238343)

Answer (score 4):

You could try directly inserting your SQL query when creating a *Virtual layer*:

```py
query = """ SELECT "MS_Area", "Ground_Con", sum("Area_Ha") as Total /*:ini*/ from final_bdry group by "MS_Area", "Ground_Con" """

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( "?query={}".format(query), "vlayer", "virtual" )
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

---

Example:

[image: Example]

---

**UPDATE for QGIS 3.0**

`QgsMapLayerRegistry` object was changed in QGIS 3.0 for `QgsProject`. So, last line in 3.0 should be:

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```