# Format Query statement for use in Virtual Layer query from PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis-3

Based on [QGIS: SQL query within python console to sum a column based on values of other two columns](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266670/qgis-sql-query-within-python-console-to-sum-a-column-based-on-values-of-other-t?rq=1)

I am trying to write a script that will get the field names to use from PyQGIS but am having issues with the format of the query statement.

I have

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
for field in layer.fields():
    current_field=field.name()
    print(current_field) 
    query = "Select", current_field, "count(*) from", layer,"group by", current_field,"order by 2 Desc"""
    print(query)
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( "?query={}".format(query), current_field, "virtual" )
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

But this is not formatting the query correctly so it comes out as

```
('Select', 'Type', 'count(*) from', <qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x00000244813FD558>, 'group by', 'Type', 'order by 2 Desc')
```

Which gives the following error

```
Query execution error on CREATE TEMP VIEW _tview AS ('Select', 'Type', 'count(*) from', <qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x00000244813FD558>, 'group by', 'Type', 'order by 2 Desc'): 1 - near "(": syntax error
```

How do I format the `query=` correctly? I have also tried it with `layer.name()`

It should be formatted as

```
Select Type, count(*) from SW_Test group by Type order by 2 Desc
```

Which results in

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `query=` line you are creating a tuple, not a string as required. Try replacing the `,` with `+` and use `layer.name()` as allready suggested:

```
query = "Select " + current_field + ", count(*) from " + layer.name() + " group by " + current_field + " order by 2 Desc"
```

or use string formatting like

```
query = "Select {0}, count(*) from {1} group by {0} order by 2 Desc".format(current_field, layer.name())
```

wich is better readable in my opinion.

Comment: Or since Python 3.6 with new f-strings : `query = f"Select {current_field}, count(*) from {layer.name()} group by {current_field} order by 2 Desc"`